# What is the maximum damage you can do per missile with the Magic Missile spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, optimization, damage

I’m currently working on a Magic Missile-centered build and want to make sure I’m not missing anything.

As far as I can tell, using Hexblade’s Curse (XGtE 53) and Empower Evocation (PHB 117) are the only ways to increase my Magic Missile damage outside of upcasting.

So assuming I have 20 Int and a proficiency bonus of +6, is 1d4+12 the maximum damage I can do per missile by RAW?

Comment: Does the related question answer your question? Do you have any restrictions on what can be used to boost the damage of your *magic missile* spell (racial traits, class/subclass features, other spells, magic items, etc.)? Any restrictions by source (core books, supplements, stuff from specific adventures, UA, certain homebrew)?

Comment: Well I did add in “by RAW” at the end so Homebrew and Unofficial UA couldn’t be added. Other than that i’m Open to classes, races, feats, and any of the official material.

Comment: This thread does answer my question. Thank you!